# Creating a list after return in R documentation

Tags: r

I am writing an `R` function and am trying to document the function using the .Rd formatting. I cannot seem to find any documentation for this, and so what I would like to know is how to create a list after `@retrun`. For example, I would like to have something like

`#' @return This list contains the following values:`

```
a some description
b some description
```

What needs to go after the `@return` to get a list that looks like using `@param`?

Comment: Wouldn't you just have `#' a some description` followed by `#' b some description`? This link suggests that the return description can have several lines in a nonproblematic way: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html

Comment: @JohnColeman the problem with that is that a and b won't be italicized. I basically want the equivalent look of using `@param`

Comment: Maybe `\code(a)` and `\code(b)` or `\emph(a)` and `\emph(b)`? This part of the documentation addresses character formatting: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#text-formatting

Answer (score 0):

I just used this:

```
#' @returns
#' A list containing the following:
#'
#' \item{mle_params}{Maximum likelihood estimates for the parameters.}
#' \item{mle_value}{The value of the log-likelihood at the maximum.}
```